# Question on understanding the first chapter of Munkres's Analysis on Manifolds

Tags: calculus, manifolds

I am reading the first chapter of Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres. In Section three, I got confused by the argument below.
[image]

[image]

My question is which parts of the theorems above are used to verify that function $f(s,t,u,v)$ is continuous in $\mathbf R^4$.

Comment: Theorem 3.6. (b) and (c)

Comment: Use 3.6(c) to get $(s,t,u,v)\mapsto s$, $(s,t,u,v)\mapsto t$, etc. are continuous.  Then use 3.6(b) to get $\dots\mapsto s+t$, $\dots\mapsto uv$ continuous.  Then use 3.5(b) to get $\dots\mapsto \sin(s+t)$, $\dots\mapsto e^{uv}$ continuous, the latter is never 0.  Finally use 3.6(b) again to get $f$.  You can probably replace some of them using 3.6(a).

Comment: Thanks, user10354138. Does Theorem 3.6, Part c) implicitly require $R^n$ and $R$ have the same metric? Of course, one with the Euclidean metric while the other with the sup metric still works.  Does it hold in general for any two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$?